# Unlocking the Bootloader on a Nexus One with S-On

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-one, fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I'm interested in rooting my (Very recently bought) nexus one, and installing Cyanogenmod over Fastboot.

However, on the boot screen of my device I've noticed the first line tells me that security is on, which disables the USB Interface in the bootloader:

```
Nexusone PVT Ship S-ON
```

On the Cyanogenmod wiki page on [Fastboot](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Fastboot), the instructions say before starting that I need to have a device with S-OFF. However, I've got the impression from trawling through forums that Nexus One phones generally come pre-set with S-OFF (in contrast to the one I just bought).

How do I turn off the Security mode on the Nexus One? i.e. How do I change S-ON to S-OFF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nexus Ones do not ship with 'S-OFF', they ship with a "locked" bootloader which then must be unlocked. You can actually use **fastboot** to unlock the bootloader, just run `fastboot oem unlock` on your PC using ADB (Android Device Bridge). MoDaCo has a post [here](http://android.modaco.com/topic/299078-how-to-unlock-the-bootloader-on-your-nexus-one/) with complete instructions and a multi-platform download of the needed tools.

Comment: Could you please mention something about S-On in your answer. While this is a way to get to the end goal, I'd still like to know what this line does, and why I should or shouldn't care about it.

Comment: S-OFF is "security off" which means the bootloader will allow you to flash ROM images that aren't signed by HTC. Fastboot oem unlock will get you S-OFF on the N1; it's one of the easiest S-OFFs to get